# sqlalchemy how to cast mixed field to date?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Journal(Base):
    __tablename__ = '_1SJOURN'
    rid = Column("ROW_ID", Integer, primary_key=True)
    journal_id = Column("IDJOURNAL", Integer)
    iddoc = Column("IDDOC", String)
    iddocdef = Column("IDDOCDEF", Integer) 
    datetime  = Column("DATE_TIME_IDDOC", String)
```

table has field DATE_TIME_IDDOC like `200809305DU3F4 65P`, first 8 chars is date. i need to select rows with date between s=20070503,e=20090503.
I tried:

```
filter(
    and_(func.convert(sql.literal_column('DATE'), Journal.datetime, sql.literal_column('1,8')) > s,
         func.convert(sql.literal_column('DATE'), Journal.datetime, sql.literal_column('1,8')) < e))
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, why can't you split "datetime" column to two columns: datetime and "other_info"? Your table's structure is not optimized. If it will looks like below, it will be easier to implement what you want. Easier and rightly.

```
class Journal(Base):
    __tablename__ = '_1SJOURN'
    rid = Column("ROW_ID", Integer, primary_key=True)
    journal_id = Column("IDJOURNAL", Integer)
    iddoc = Column("IDDOC", String)
    iddocdef = Column("IDDOCDEF", Integer) 
    datetime = Column("DATE_TIME", DateTime)
    other = Column("OTHER", String)

# here I do not use `and_`, because it used by default
Session.query(Journal).filter(Journal.datetime > s, Journal.datetime < e)
```

But, if you really want it, that is your query. Raw SQL (for Postgresql, other DBMSes have the same functions but with another names):

```
SELECT * FROM journal WHERE to_timestamp(left(DATE_TIME_IDDOC, 8), 'YYYYMMDD') > '2008-10-01' AND to_timestamp(left(DATE_TIME_IDDOC, 8), 'YYYYMMDD') < '2010-01-20';
```

SQLAlchemy query:

```
filter_col = func.to_timestamp(func.left(Journal.datetime, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')
Session.query(Journal).filter(filter_col > s, filter_col < e)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
and_(func.convert(sql.literal_column('datetime'),func.substring(Journal.datetime, 1,8)) > s ,
             func.convert(sql.literal_column('datetime'), func.substring(Journal.datetime, 1, 8)) < e)).filter(
```